# Android custom keyboard popup

Tags: android, keyboard, popup

I have a custom android keyboard. On long press popup keyboard is shown how it should. The problem is, when it pops up, the keyboard behind is darkenes.
How can i disable this, except overriding the default KeyboardView onDraw?

One more thing: how can I make the poped up keyboard buttons selected without pressing on them? In Google keyboard, when you press on a "." key, you just keep moving your finger and it selects the key on the popup. But on the default implementation of KeyboardView, you have to press on the key.

This has been bugging me for a month, hope you can help!

Answer (score 3):

Solution:  don't use KeyboardView.  Its meant for quick prototyping, when you need a basic keyboard and are working on other things like autocorrect algorithms.  No serious keyboard actually uses it, and it isn't required (you can return any view from onCreateInputView).  As you ramp up UI complexity, it just quickly becomes unable to deal

Comment: Ok thank you. How would then I make the popup view selected when i hold the button on my custom kb view? I dont want the user to have to press the poped up view, keeping the finger on the screen and sliding would be preffered.